Upgrade Visual Studio 2015 to 2022: Resource File is corrupt after edit in VS 2022
I have a Visual-C++ Win32 Project, which I developed with Visual Studio 2015. Now I made an upgrade to Visual Studio 2022.
All works fine, except every time I make a small change, like just move a button or anything else and save, the <project>.rc file is completely changed - this is ok because it is rebuilt by the wizard, but the IDs are partially changed.
For example:
CONTROL         Zahnreader2,-1,"Static",SS_BITMAP | SS_CENTERIMAGE | SS_SUNKEN | WS_BORDER,7,7,97,130

is changed to:
CONTROL         VK_NONAME,-1,"Static",SS_BITMAP | SS_CENTERIMAGE | SS_SUNKEN | WS_BORDER,7,7,97,130

After this, I can't build because some keywords can not be found (WS_EX_COMPOSITED, VK_GAMEPAD_B).
When upgrading from 2015 to 2022, I also the following steps:

Additionaly installed Visual Studio 2015 because of .net 4.5 for c#
Installed MFC.
Set struct alignment to standard.
Retarged Solution to latest installed versions.

At the moment, I can edit the <project>.rc with a text-editor, which works. But how can I get back to edit resources inside Visual Studio?

Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?
See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

@MinxinYu-MSFT: Sorry but the file is very large and I'm not authorized to share it.

It is hard to identify the cause of the problem based on current information.
